# Using Scanner inside a for loop for system input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been struggling with this for a while. I essentially want to loop through and read in as many strings  as determined by `num_choices`. The following code only executes the else condition.

```
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i=0; i < this.num_choices; i++)
        {
          if(s2.hasNext())
          {

            System.out.println("Enter choice " + (i+1) +":");
            String ch = s2.next();
            //this.choices.addElement(ch);
          }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Lets end this");

        }

    }
```

`

I am getting this: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException`. In the main class, this is where the error points to

```
        choice2 = Integer.parseInt(read_choice2.next());
```

which is inside a while loop as well. Here is the code for that:

```
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    Vector<Survey> mysurveys = new Vector<Survey>();
    boolean carry_on = true;
    int choice = 0;
    Scanner read_choice = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Let's begin the Survey/Test application!");
    while(carry_on)
    {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1. Create a new Survey");
        System.out.println("2. Create a new Test");
        System.out.println("3. Display a Survey");
        System.out.println("4. Display a Test");
        System.out.println("5. Save a Survey");
        System.out.println("6. Save a Test");
        System.out.println("7. Load a Survey");
        System.out.println("8. Load a Test");
        System.out.println("9. Quit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter a number for the operation you want to perform: ");
        choice = Integer.parseInt(read_choice.next());
        /*try
        {
            choice = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());

        }
        catch(InputMismatchException  e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input. Please Enter again.");
            System.out.println();
            //read_choice.nextInt();
        }*/

        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Name for your Survey");
            String in = buffer.readLine();
            Survey s1 = new Survey();
            s1.CreateNew(in);
            mysurveys.add(s1);
            ////
            add_question(s1.type);
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Name for your Test");
            //String in = buffer.readLine();
            Test t1 = new Test();
            //t1.CreateNew(in);
            mysurveys.add(t1);
            break;
            ////
            //add_question(t1.type);
        case 3:


            break;
            // call Survey.display()


        case 4:


            break;


        case 5:

            Survey s = new Survey();
            ReadWriteFiles x = new ReadWriteFiles();
            x.SaveSurvey(s);
            break;


        case 6:

            Test t = new Test();
            //ReadWriteFiles x = new ReadWriteFiles();
            //x.SaveSurvey(t);
            break;


        case 7:

            carry_on = false;
            break;

        default:

            System.out.println("Incorrect Input. Try Again");
            System.out.println();
            break;
        }
    }

    read_choice.close();


}







 public static void add_question(String type) throws IOException, NullPointerException
 {
Questions q = null;
boolean carry_on2 = true;
int choice2 = 0;
Scanner read_choice2 = new Scanner(System.in);
//BufferedReader buffer2=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while (carry_on2)
{
    //
    System.out.println("1. Add a new T/F Question");
    System.out.println("2. Add a new Multiple Choice Question");
    System.out.println("3. Add a new Short Answer Question");
    System.out.println("4. Add a new Essay Question");
    System.out.println("5. Add a new Ranking Question");
    System.out.println("6. Add a new Matching Question");
    System.out.println("7. If you want to stop adding more questions, and go back to the main menu.");
    System.out.println("Please enter a number for the operation you want to perform: ");
    choice2 = Integer.parseInt(read_choice2.next());

    /*try
    {
        choice2 = Integer.parseInt(buffer2.readLine());

    }
    catch(InputMismatchException  e)
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Please Enter again.");
        System.out.println();
        //read_choice2.nextInt();
    }*/
    switch(choice2)
    {
        case 1:
            q = new TrueFalse();
            break;
        case 2:
            q = new MultipleChoice();
            break;
        case 3:
            q = new ShortAnswer();
            break;
        case 4:
            q = new Essay();
            break;
        case 5:
            q = new Ranking();
            break;
        case 6:
            q = new Matching();
            break;
        case 7:
            carry_on2 = false;
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Incorrect Input.");
            break;

    }
    q.createQuestion(type);

}
}
}
```

I realize there is a lot of messy code, and I apologize for that. I just wanted to show the entire thing, so it's easier to spot the problem. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In general way, you should add `if(read_choice.hasNext())` before invoking `read_choice.next();` You have the exception `java.util.NoSuchElementException` because no elements found to be read. this is a good habit.

About your problem, you are getting error because you has closed scanner before finish reading. Put `read_choice.close()` outside of loop.

Moreover, for simplify, if you want to read integer, just simple : `scanner.nextInt()`.

Comment: You should see again other method, does it create new scanner object ? because Scanner should close only once. So, you should pass scanner object (read_choice) to another method, rather than create new one and close that.

Answer (score 0):

```
read_choice.close();
```

Don't close the scanner as long as you are not done reading all the inputs. Doing also closes the underlying input stream (`System.in`), check the [documention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close%28%29);

You don't need to initialize the `Scanner` multiple times. Just create one instance and pass it around (keep using it).

Also,

```
for(int i=0; i < this.num_choices; i++)
{
   //if(s2.hasNext())
   //{

       System.out.println("Enter choice " + (i+1) +":");
       String ch = s2.next();
       //this.choices.addElement(ch);
```

you don't need that condition check. The `next()` will block until the input is entered.

Comment: @dawnoflife: What did you do? Is it the same exception?

Comment: I removed the if conditional, commented out in your comment and removed the `read_choice.close()` call.                                  Now I get `Enter choice 1:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at MultipleChoice.createQuestion(MultipleChoice.java:34)
 at Main.add_question(Main.java:185)
 at Main.main(Main.java:54)
`

Comment: @dawnoflife: Try replacing next() with nextLine(). Also, what is buffer? I don't understand your case 1. Don't do `new Scanner(System.in)` multiple times.

Comment: Case 1 just pushes off the activity to another function. It's supposed to call the `createQuestion()` method which resides in 6 different classes. Does that make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18649/discussion-between-dawnoflife-and-bhesh-gurung)